# Bootstrap buttons keep disappearing upon executing my java script code

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a table, where upon clicking a button, the java script will fill in the cells with a 'value'.

Currently however, my buttons are also disappearing at the end of each row in my table upon clicking the button. I tried placing them outside of my table(outside of the td), but when I click my button, they disappear again.

Does any one have any idea on what I can do to make them stay?

Comment: what happened to your markup?

Comment: you should use the jquery append function instead of replacing all the html

Comment: Im sorry, I don't follow, my markup?

Comment: your html is missing all the html tags "<"

Comment: It's currently in PUG syntax

Comment: can you paste the rendered html instead?

Comment: Hollow's tend to disappear when executed as well. Maybe your buttons are really hollows! :P

Comment: sure thing, just 1 second

Comment: updated. By hollows, do you mean buttons that don't do anything?

Comment: not sure if it will be an issue for you but ID attributes in older standards of html cannot begin with numbers also `<th type="button" class="button btn btn-success">Compress All</th>` doesn't look like valid html

Comment: oh ok, yea I removed them, they weren't really being used for anything

Comment: It might just be because of the pug to html converter I used to show my code in proper syntax

Comment: trying to understand more cearly. What is that you want to happen when they click on the btn-update? What would like your table row to look like?

Comment: another thing i noticed is that you have multiple elements with the same id attribute.

Comment: So upon clicking my button, I would like for everything except for my headers and my buttons at the end of each row to update to "value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You replacing the whole html for your table,.
With jQuery you can just replace the existing cells..

Example below.. ->

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {


    var data1 = [ //needs to be changed to something that generates a random #
        { field1: 'value a1', field2: 'value a2', field3: 'value a3', field4: 'value a4', field5: 'value a5' },
        { field1: 'value b1', field2: 'value b2', field3: 'value b3', field4: 'value b4', field5: 'value b5' },
        { field1: 'value c1', field2: 'value c2', field3: 'value c3', field4: 'value c4', field5: 'value c5' }
        ];
    function loadTable(tableId, fields, data) {
        //$('#' + tableId).empty(); //not really necessary
        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
            var $row = $('#data-table tbody tr:nth-child(' + (index+1) + ')');
            $.each(fields, function(index, field) {
              var $col = $row.find('td:nth-child(' + (index+1) + ')');
              $col.text(item[fields[index]]);
            });
        });
    }

    $('#btn-update').click(function (e) {
        loadTable('data-table', ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4',], data1);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Video </th>
        <th>Size </th>
        <th>Compressed Size</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th type="button" class="button btn btn-success">Compress All </th>
        <th type="button" class="button btn btn-danger">Delete All</th>
        <th type="button" class="button btn btn-primary">Download All</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="1">Video 1 File Name</td>
        <td id="2">Original File Size</td>
        <td id="3">Estimated File Size after compression</td>
        <td id="4">Amount Saved</td>
        <td>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-compressed"></span></button>
          <button id="delete" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
          <button id="download" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Video 2 File Name</td>
        <td>Original File Size</td>
        <td>Estimated File Size after compression</td>
        <td>Amount Saved</td>
        <td>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-compressed"></span></button>
          <button id="delete" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
          <button id="download" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt">                 </span></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Video 3 File Name</td>
        <td>Original File Size</td>
        <td>Estimated File Size after compression</td>
        <td>Amount Saved     </td>
        <td>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-compressed"></span></button>
          <button id="delete" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
          <button id="download" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt">                 </span></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<button id="btn-update">Randomize</button>
```

Comment: This it! Thank you so much, I had no Idea you could replace existing cells

Answer (score 0):

there were some issues with the markup there were multiple elements with the same ID
`<th type="button" class="button btn btn-success">Compress All</th>` is invalid html

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  var data1 = [ //needs to be changed to something that generates a random #
    {
      field1: 'value a1',
      field2: 'value a2',
      field3: 'value a3',
      field4: 'value a4',
      field5: 'value a5'
    }, {
      field1: 'value b1',
      field2: 'value b2',
      field3: 'value b3',
      field4: 'value b4',
      field5: 'value b5'
    }, {
      field1: 'value c1',
      field2: 'value c2',
      field3: 'value c3',
      field4: 'value c4',
      field5: 'value c5'
    }
  ];

  function loadTable(tableId, fields, data) {
    //$('#' + tableId).empty(); //not really necessary
    var rows = '';
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
      var row = '<tr>';
      $.each(fields, function(index, field) {
        row += '<td>' + item[field + ''] + '</td>';
        
      });
      row+= '<td>          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-compressed"></span>          </button>        </td>        <td>          <button id="" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>          </button>        </td>        <td>          <button id="" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm download"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>          </button>        </td>';
      rows += row + '<tr>';
    });
    $('#' + tableId + ' tbody').html(rows);
  }

  $('#btn-update').click(function(e) {
    loadTable('data-table', ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', ], data1);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Video</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Compressed Size</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>
          <button type="button" class="button btn btn-success">Compress All</button>
        </th>
        <th>
          <button type="button" class="button btn btn-danger">Delete All</button>
        </th>
        <th>
          <button type="button" class="button btn btn-primary">Download All</button>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="1">Video 1 File Name</td>
        <td id="2">Original File Size</td>
        <td id="3">Estimated File Size after compression</td>
        <td id="4">Amount Saved</td>
        <td>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-compressed"></span>
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button id="" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button id="" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm download"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Video 2 File Name</td>
        <td>Original File Size</td>
        <td>Estimated File Size after compression</td>
        <td>Amount Saved</td>
        <td>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-compressed"></span>
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button id= "" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button id="" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm download"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt">                 </span>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Video 3 File Name</td>
        <td>Original File Size</td>
        <td>Estimated File Size after compression</td>
        <td>Amount Saved</td>
        <td>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-compressed"></span>
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button id="" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button id="" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm download"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt">                  </span>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button id="btn-update">Randomize</button> 
</body>
```